# How to save and persist selected cell check mark in UITableView using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In myscenario, I am trying to load `JSON` data into my `tableview`. Here, I am using multiple cell selection in a tableview. I need to `persist` selected cell `checkmark`. if I go another view controller and comeback to see tableview selected check mark need to show.

**My Code**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let item = searching ? filteredData[indexPath.row] : membersData[indexPath.row]

    if selectedRows.contains(indexPath.row) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    } else {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = 
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to save and persist the selected indexPaths in the dataSource itself.

Comment: @PGDev I need to save and persist Userdefault. Just want to do next time if we open tableview last selected info need to show.

Comment: Then you can just save the selected indexes in the UserDefaults whenever a cell is selected.

Comment: @PGDev sorry. I am new for this want to learn from some code. could you please provide some code sample?

Comment: @PGDev multiple cell check mark I am using

Comment: You can use only 1 array that was define globally and that stored your data's unique value and then you can check that your global array contains your current row unique value or not and as per that you need to set `.none` or `.checkmark` inside the `cellForRow`

Comment: @Kuldeep Please provide some code

Comment: @PGDev can you please provide me some sample?

Comment: @RajeshKumar R Please help me on this

Comment: You should find something in your json that uniquely identifies a row and then store that value in user defaults for each checked row so that you later on can find each row even if the order has changed or items has been added or removed.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if you don't mind post some example based on it I will try and update here. I hardly trying from two days till now didn't get working method.