# Swift persist and retrive UITableview cell checkmark

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am loading `JSON` data into Tableview. My tableview allowing multiple selection `checkmark` option. Now, I can’t able to `store` selected cell checkmark. How to do it?

`NOTE:` JSON data array count may be increase in future

**My Tableview Code**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TeamlistCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! TeamlistCustomCell
        let textForRow = searching ? filteredData[indexPath.row] : membersData[indexPath.row]        
        cell.name.text = textForRow.firstname
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let item = searching ? filteredData[indexPath.row] : membersData[indexPath.row]

        if selectedValues.contains(item) { //deselect
            selectedRows.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
            selectedValues.remove(item)
        } else {
            selectedRows.append(indexPath.row) //select
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            selectedValues.insert(item)
        }

        // Selected Row Index Store
        UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedRows, forKey: "SelectedIndexes")
    }
```

Comment: @RushabhShah Its not relevant to my question. Please remove it buddy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save and persist selected cell check mark in UITableView using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692338/how-to-save-and-persist-selected-cell-check-mark-in-uitableview-using-swift)

Comment: Kindly don't post duplicate question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692338/how-to-save-and-persist-selected-cell-check-mark-in-uitableview-using-swift

Comment: @vadian is there anything possibility to without adding Bool var into JSON data. I have to achieve this ASAP. Please provide some idea

Comment: @vadian please provide me some solution

Answer (score -1):

By Using below mentioned property, you can get all your selected rows index paths.

```
var indexPathsForSelectedRows: [IndexPath]? { get }
```

**Example:**

```
let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

**Next Step**

After reloading the tableView, Create a separate method and write a code to select all previously selected cells.

```
func selectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath?, 
      animated: Bool, 
scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition)
```

**Example**

```
func updateTableState(tableView: UITableView) -> Void {

tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.forEach({ (indexPath) in
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        })

}
```

**YOUR CODE with Solution**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TeamlistCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! TeamlistCustomCell
        let textForRow = searching ? filteredData[indexPath.row] : membersData[indexPath.row]
        cell.name.text = textForRow.firstname
        return cell
    }

    func updateTableState(tableView: UITableView) -> Void {
            tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.forEach({ (indexPath) in
                tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
            })
    }

    func reloadData() {
        tableView.reloadData()
        updateTableState(tableView: tableView)
    }

    func getAllSelectedObjects() -> [String]//mention whatever type array you have  {
        let selectedObjects = [String]() //mention whatever type array you have
        tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.forEach({ (indexPath) in
            let object = searching ? filteredData[indexPath.row] : membersData[indexPath.row]
            selectedObjects.append(object)
        })
        return selectedObjects
    }
```

Comment: Yes Thank you! Btw how to validate and assign my checkmark again. Because if I reopen my tableview controller Its all gone.

Comment: While reloading the table next time , you need to put a check on your "cellForRow" method to select your previously selected row to set as selected by using  ``` func selectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath?, 
      animated: Bool, 
scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition)```

Comment: If you don't mind could please update your code exact one.

Comment: Where I need to put this line `let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows`?

Comment: I am extremely sorry. I can't able to pick your answer. Could you please update my code?

Comment: I am bit confused. Check my posted code. I have to modify it. where I need to place this `let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` and within this function what I need to do`func selectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath?, 
      animated: Bool, 
scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition)`

Comment: After reloading your table just add that method call in next line...

Comment: Do not create any extra variable to hold selected rows, remove your "didSelectRow" method code and use my code to maintain the state.

Comment: seriously I can't get your idea. If you have free time please modify my code and post it. I am not getting some idea from above. Need more code buddy.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson which one is best solution provide me please

Comment: @iosdev see full solution